# How to know which button was pressed inside a QButtonGroup?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qbuttongroup

I have a function that create a frame and place a line edit and a button inside of it, then it places the button on QButtonGroup:

```
self.btn_group = QButtonGroup(self.ui_main.scrollArea_content)

def new(self):
    # Create the frame
    self.ui_main.frame_content = QFrame(self.ui_main.scrollArea_content)
    self.ui_main.frame_content.setObjectName(f"frame_content_{self.counter}")
    self.ui_main.frame_content.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 70))
    self.ui_main.frame_content.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
    self.ui_main.frame_content.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
    # Create horizontal layout
    self.ui_main.horizontalLayout_4 = QHBoxLayout(self.ui_main.frame_content)
    self.ui_main.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName(f"horizontalLayout_4_{self.counter}")
    # Create line edit content
    self.ui_main.line_content = QLineEdit(self.ui_main.frame_content)
    self.ui_main.line_content.setObjectName(f"line_content_{self.counter}")
    # Add line edit content to horizontal layout
    self.ui_main.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.ui_main.line_content)
    # Create the button remove
    self.ui_main.btn_remove = QPushButton(self.ui_main.frame_content)
    self.ui_main.btn_remove.setObjectName(f"btn_remove_{self.counter}")
    self.ui_main.btn_remove.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 50))
    self.ui_main.btn_remove.setMaximumSize(QSize(80, 16777215))
    self.ui_main.btn_remove.setText(u"Remove")
    # Add button remove to horizontal layout
    self.ui_main.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.ui_main.btn_remove)
    # Add the frame content(contains line edit and button) to vertical layout
    self.ui_main.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.ui_main.frame_content, 0, Qt.AlignTop)
    # Add button to group
    self.btn_group.addButton(self.ui_main.btn_remove)
    # Increment the counter to name the next button
    self.counter += 1
```

After that i have the connection to the button group to initialize the remove function, that will remove the entire frame containing the line edit and the button

```
self.btn_group.buttonClicked.connect(self.remove)
```

But with button group i was able to know only if any button was clicked, not which button was clicked, the buttonClicked method returns a button group object that contains nothing about the clicked button, there is a way to know which button was pressed inside QButtonGroup? if not how could i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`buttonClicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#buttonClicked) signal sends the button that was clicked:

```
def remove(self, button):
    print(button, button.text())
```

Demo:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(view)
    group = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup()
    for i in range(5):
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f"button-{i}")
        lay.addWidget(button)
        group.addButton(button)
    view.show()

    def handle_button_clicked(button):
        print(button, button.text())

    group.buttonClicked.connect(handle_button_clicked)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked exactly as i wanted, the problem was in the remove function i was calling self.sender() and was receiving a button group object.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to number your buttons with `id` as you add them to the group, you can use the [idClicked(int id)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#idClicked) signal. There are some use cases where it is easier to work with id numbers than with button names.

Example (heavily borrowed from @eyllanesc excellent answer):

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(view)
    group = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup()
    for i in range(5):
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f"button-{i}")
        lay.addWidget(button)
        group.addButton(button, i)
    view.show()

    def handle_button_idclicked(id_):
        print('id of button is ', id_)
        print('text of button is ', group.button(id_).text())

    group.idClicked.connect(handle_button_idclicked)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it's being easier to work with id.